# PyInstaller 3.2 - Looking for dynamic libraries

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, pyinstaller

When using latest version of PyInstaller, the build hangs on this line

15720 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries

It takes 10-15 minutes to get past. Eventually when it has finished, the build sometimes works and sometimes it doesnt.

Im having trouble getting image files into my exe as well so im having to tweak things and rebuild, its just not viable with this length of time to build.

Only one page I could find on the issue is [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2022), with a reply linking to another page and suggesting "Run PyInstaller from a source checkout until the new release is out." which I dont know how to do.

The other page linked to [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1920) is mostly over my head but seems like they have found an issue and recommended a fix, but I have the latest release installed and the problem remains.

Does anyone have any idea and is it possible to install an older version of PyInstaller perhaps? Im using Pip to install.

EDIT: Looking further I found a link to install the latest developer version and it has fixed the problem.

pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip

Comment: pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip worked for me too, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Same issue here with the release downloaded from pip...I'll try the github url...thanks

Comment: Update: I download the zip file from github link you provided which solved the issue... :D :D